# Merge two files: two lines, partial line, two lines, partial line, etc

Tags: text-processing, awk

Hello I am trying to use `awk` to merge two text files in a rather peculiar way,
taking two lines from `file1`, a group of word(s) from `file2`
(but placed on a separate line), alternating *ad infinitum*. 
Groups of word(s) from `file2` are delimited by commas. 
For example:

`file1`

```
A Partridge in a Pear Tree
Two Turtle Doves
Three French Hens
Four Calling Birds
Five Gold Rings
Six Geese a-Laying
Seven Swans a-Swimming
Eight Maids a-Milking
Nine Ladies Dancing
Ten Lords a-Leaping
Eleven Pipers Piping
Twelve Drummers Drumming
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore—
While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,
As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
“’Tis some visitor,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door—
            Only this and nothing more.”
```

`file2`

```
I was born, on Mars, the red planet
I love frogs, they are so tasty, with, ketchup, I am hungry
```

Output file

```
A Partridge in a Pear Tree
Two Turtle Doves
I was born
Three French Hens
Four Calling Birds
on Mars
Five Gold Rings
Six Geese a-Laying
the red planet
Seven Swans a-Swimming
Eight Maids a-Milking
I love frogs
Nine Ladies Dancing
Ten Lords a-Leaping
they are so tasty
Eleven Pipers Piping
Twelve Drummers Drumming
with
Once upon a midnight dreary, while I pondered, weak and weary,
Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore—
ketchup
While I nodded, nearly napping, suddenly there came a tapping,
As of some one gently rapping, rapping at my chamber door.
I am hungry
“’Tis some visitor,” I muttered, “tapping at my chamber door—
            Only this and nothing more.”
```

Details:

- `file1` is split into couplets of two lines, regardless of content
- A line in `file2` may have any number of groups (i.e., any number of commas)
- A group in `file2` may have any number of words (including zero???)
- `file1` and `file2` may be arbitrarily long
- Desired behavior when you reach the end of one file
  but still have data in the other is unspecified.

How do I do this?

Comment: Please ***define*** (describe) your problem. Is `file1` split after every two lines, based on some content of the file, pre-specified line numbers, or something else?  Is `file2` split after every three words, based on the commas, based on some content of the words, or something else?  Is it guaranteed that `file2` will always have exactly one line?

Comment: Thanks for fast reaction:).  
I asked a question inaccurately.

File1 is split after every two lines pre-specified line numbers.
File2 split after every three words, based on the commas. 

Scott asked : Is it guaranteed that file2 will always have exactly one line? 

Unfortunately not :(. File 1 and file2 have a random number of lines.

Comment: (1) An example of “Insert[ing] a **line** at a specified line number” would be inserting a line at line 42. An example of “Insert[ing] lines at specified line **numbers**” would be inserting lines at lines 1, 4, 9, 17 and 42. Inserting after every two lines isn’t really an example of either of these. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) My second question was whether `File2` is supposed to be split after every three words ***or*** based on the commas, or something else.  By saying “File2 [is] split after every three words, based on the commas,” you give us no guidance regarding how to handle a `File2` line like “The quick brown fox, jumps over, the lazy dog.”  If you are guaranteeing the `File2` has a comma after every third word, you should mention that.  Although, I guess, by putting “Paris11”, “22London”, and “Berlin33” on separate lines, you’ve hinted that we should ignore word count in `File2`. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) Your new example is inconsistent with your first one, unless there’s some more complex rule hiding in the woodwork that you’ve forgotten to mention. (“in the earth” should come after “4Ubuntu dd dddd” and “beyond the land” should come after “6Aix fff fff”.) … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … (99) Therefore, I have voted to close this question as unclear. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … P.S. If one (or more) of the posted answers satisfy your requirements (whatever they are), you should say so — in comments, and by “accepting” the best one.

Comment: Stick to the first version Questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you want to insert the sentence which are in between comma of the `file2` after every 2 line of `file1`, you can try the following `awk` script:

```
 awk -F", *" 'NR==FNR{
                 for(i=1;i<NF+1;i++)
                    a[i]=$i
              } 
              NR>FNR{
                 print; 
                 if(FNR%2==0) 
                     print a[FNR/2]
              }' file2 file1
```

Comment: Note that it assumes `file2` contains one an only one non-empty line.

Comment: Could you explain how it works, step by step

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas  said: Note that it assumes file2 contains one an only one non-empty line.
Is it possible to modify this code to the line in the file2 can be more?
Any quantity.
But always less than file1.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F ', *' '!skip {for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) a[++n] = $i; next}
              {print}
              FNR % 2 == 0 && m++ < n {print a[m]}
             ' file2 skip=1 file1
```

Comment: Ha!  The Stack Exchange Ogre says, "This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its **length** and **content**."

Comment: You bored with `FNR==NR` to use `skip`, didn't it? ;)

Comment: @Costas, the problem with `NR==FNR` is that it doesn't work correctly when the first file may be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that @oliv's interpretation is correct, this solution might also work, although it does not use `awk`:

```
paste -d '\n ' file1 <(sed  's/^/\n/;s/, */\n\n/g' file2) | sed '/^$/d'
```

Given the *updated* requirements of the OP, this no longer seems a viable approach.

Comment: Nice idea, but much easy `cat file1 | paste -d'\n' - - <(sed 's/, /\n/g' file2)`

Comment: @Costas Silly me! I forgot that `paste` can handle any number of files.

Answer (score 1):

Play with **awk**'s `R`ecord`S`eparator (here assuming GNU `awk` or recent versions of `mawk`)

```
awk '{print}!(NR%2){getline <"file2";print}' RS="\n|, " file1
```

If there are `,` in *file1*'s line(s), a more correct version could be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{r=RS}{print}!(NR%2){RS=r"|, ";getline <"file2";print;RS=r}' file1
```

Modified question can be settled (portably) by

```
awk '{print};!(NR%2) && (getline <"file2")>0{gsub(", *", "\n");print}' file1
```

Comment: It's record separator.