# Replacing matching entries in one column of a file by another column from a different file

Tags: awk

I have two tab-separated files which look as follows:

file1:

```
NC_008146.1     WP_011558474.1  1155234 1156286 44173
NC_008146.1     WP_011558475.1  1156298 1156807 12
NC_008146.1     WP_011558476.1  1156804 1157820 -3
NC_008705.1     WP_011558474.1  1159543 1160595 42748
NC_008705.1     WP_011558475.1  1160607 1161116 12
NC_008705.1     WP_011558476.1  1161113 1162129 -3
NC_009077.1     WP_011559727.1  2481079 2481633 8
NC_009077.1     WP_011854835.1  1163068 1164120 42559
NC_009077.1     WP_011854836.1  1164127 1164636 7
```

file2:

```
NC_008146.1     GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa
NC_008705.1     GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa
NC_009077.1     GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa
```

I want to match column 1 of file1 to file2 and replace itself with the respective column 2 entry of file 2.
The output would look like this:

```
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa     WP_011558474.1  1155234 1156286 44173
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa     WP_011558475.1  1156298 1156807 12
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa     WP_011558476.1  1156804 1157820 -3
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa     WP_011558474.1  1159543 1160595 42748
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa     WP_011558475.1  1160607 1161116 12
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa     WP_011558476.1  1161113 1162129 -3
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa     WP_011559727.1  2481079 2481633 8
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa     WP_011854835.1  1163068 1164120 42559
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa     WP_011854836.1  1164127 1164636 7
```

Comment: It looks like you might also be interested in our sister site: [bioinformatics.se].

Comment: Thank you for the link @terdon!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this very easily with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}{$1=a[$1]; print}' file2 file1
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa WP_011558474.1 1155234 1156286 44173
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa WP_011558475.1 1156298 1156807 12
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa WP_011558476.1 1156804 1157820 -3
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa WP_011558474.1 1159543 1160595 42748
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa WP_011558475.1 1160607 1161116 12
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa WP_011558476.1 1161113 1162129 -3
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa WP_011559727.1 2481079 2481633 8
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa WP_011854835.1 1163068 1164120 42559
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa WP_011854836.1 1164127 1164636 7
```

Or, since that looks like a tab-separated file:

```
$ awk -vOFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}{$1=a[$1]; print}' file2 file1
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa   WP_011558474.1  1155234 1156286 44173
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa   WP_011558475.1  1156298 1156807 12
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa   WP_011558476.1  1156804 1157820 -3
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa   WP_011558474.1  1159543 1160595 42748
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa   WP_011558475.1  1160607 1161116 12
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa   WP_011558476.1  1161113 1162129 -3
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa   WP_011559727.1  2481079 2481633 8
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa   WP_011854835.1  1163068 1164120 42559
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa   WP_011854836.1  1164127 1164636 7
```

This assumes that every RefSeq (`NC_*`) id in `file1` has a corresponding entry in `file2`.

#### Explanation

- `NR==FNR` : NR is the current line number, FNR is the line number of the current file. The two will be identical only while the 1st file (here, `file2`) is being read.
- `a[$1]=$2; next`: if this is the first file (see above), save the 2nd field in an array whose key is the 1st field. Then, move on to the `next` line. This ensures the next block isn't executed for the 1st file.
- `{$1=a[$1]; print}` : now, in the second file, set the 1st field to whatever value was saved in the array `a` for the 1st field (so, the associated value from `file2`) and print the resulting line.

Comment: `NR == FNR` doesn't work correctly when the first file is empty. See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297050/merge-two-files-two-lines-partial-line-two-lines-partial-line-etc/297053#comment521751_297053) and the associated answer for a workaround

Comment: @iruvar nothing will work well if the first file is empty, so I don't really see why that's relevant. The entire point here is to combine the data from the two files. If either file is empty, the whole exercise is pointless.

Comment: sorry I should have said in this particular case `file2` and not `file1` is empty. Sane behaviour when `file2` is empty is to report the contents of `file1`. The problem with `NR == FNR` is that code associated with it executes on the contents of `file1` when `file2` is empty

Comment: @iruvar there is no sane behavior here if either file is empty. That's what I'm saying :) So trying to make it deal with that case gracefully is pointless. And, in any case, when either file is empty here, nothing is printed. Which actually seems like the sanest approach, I'd rather get no data than wrong data.

Answer (score 17):

No need for awk, assuming the files are sorted, you can use coreutils join:

```
join -o '2.2 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa     WP_011558474.1  1155234 1156286 44173
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa     WP_011558475.1  1156298 1156807 12
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa     WP_011558476.1  1156804 1157820 -3
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa     WP_011558474.1  1159543 1160595 42748
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa     WP_011558475.1  1160607 1161116 12
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa     WP_011558476.1  1161113 1162129 -3
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa     WP_011559727.1  2481079 2481633 8
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa     WP_011854835.1  1163068 1164120 42559
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa     WP_011854836.1  1164127 1164636 7
```

If your files aren't, sorted, you can either sort them first (`sort file1 > file1.sorted; sort file2 > file2.sorted`) and then use the command above, or, if your shell supports the `<()` construct (bash does), you can do:

```
join -o '2.2 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5' <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested with below command  and worked fine

```
for i in `awk '{print $1}' f2`; do k=`awk -v i="$i" '$1==i {print $2}' f2`;sed  "/$i/s/$i/$k/g" f1 >f3;done
```

output

```
for i in `awk '{print $1}' f2`; do k=`awk -v i="$i" '$1==i {print $2}' f2`;sed  "/$i/s/$i/$k/g" f1 >f3;done


GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa     WP_011558474.1  1155234 1156286 44173
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa     WP_011558475.1  1156298 1156807 12
GCF_000014165.1_ASM1416v1_protein.faa     WP_011558476.1  1156804 1157820 -3
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa     WP_011558474.1  1159543 1160595 42748
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa     WP_011558475.1  1160607 1161116 12
GCF_000015405.1_ASM1540v1_protein.faa     WP_011558476.1  1161113 1162129 -3
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa     WP_011559727.1  2481079 2481633 8
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa     WP_011854835.1  1163068 1164120 42559
GCF_000016005.1_ASM1600v1_protein.faa     WP_011854836.1  1164127 1164636 7
```